# Is there are iterative version of groupBy in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have iterator with a lot of items so I can't convert it to Iterable for groupBy and don't want to sotre all results in memmory.
But I know that all object are ordered by groupBy field so it seems possible to implement groupBy for sorted iterators... Is there already some method in scala collection to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:

```
 def iterativeGroupBy[T, B](iterO: Iterator[T])(func: T => B): Iterator[List[T]] = new Iterator[List[T]] {
    var iter = iterO
    def hasNext = iter.hasNext

    def next = {
      val first = iter.next()
      val firstValue = func(first)
      val (i1,i2) = iter.span(el => func(el) == firstValue)
      iter = i2
      first :: i1.toList
    }
  }
```

Comment: It must be noted that this code does quite the other thing than `groupBy` on other collections. "Real" group by needs to traverse the entire collection anyway, so I suspect that you can't have the in-memory solution.

Comment: But, assuming "all object are ordered by groupBy field" both methods equal.

Comment: Ah. Missed that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Weird that `groupBy` isn't on `Iterator`, but how about this?

```
val it = Iterator(1, 2, 3)
new Iterable[Int] { def iterator = it }.groupBy(_ % 2 == 0)
```

It seems to work (though it's by no means guaranteed, given that one *should* produce the same iterator every time with `Iterable`).

Comment: This is in-memory solution,  but I want to group-by infinite size collection the same way as most SQL databases...